# Why react won't set the state after Redux action trigger?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I have tried to set the state locally in the component after the redux trigger but it just did not work, what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    <TableCell
        onClick={() => {
          if (dropDownLocation === "allLocations") {
            overlayDisplay("open");
          } else {
            console.log(values.rescheduleDate);
            getReservationsByDate(row.reservation_date); // Redux action
            getStaffMember(row.staff_name); // Redux action
            setValues((prevState) => {
              return {
                ...prevState,
                rescheduleDate: true, // always logged as false
              };
            });
          }
        }}
      >CLICK</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Redux's actions are dispatched synchronously, so here you can use async-await to do async operations.

```
 <TableCell
    onClick={async () => {
      if (dropDownLocation === "allLocations") {
        overlayDisplay("open");
      } else {
        console.log(values.rescheduleDate);
        await getReservationsByDate(row.reservation_date); // Redux action
        await getStaffMember(row.staff_name); // Redux action
        await setValues((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            rescheduleDate: true, // always logged as false
          };
        });
      }
    }}
  >CLICK</TableCell>
```

Comment: Even if this did what you think it does it still wouldn't solve the issue.

Comment: Same thing, I still don't see rescheduleDate value "true".

Comment: @Noor Would you able to show more code here, what is dropDownLocation?, Earlier setValues previous states, etc

Comment: @Abhijeet 

   `const [values, setValues] = useState({
      rescheduleDate: false,
      rescheduleTime: false,
      hours: {},
    });`

dropDownLocation is just a sting coming from redux state.